# Pass python list from context to JS function

Tags: python, django

I have a view that renders a dictionary of data for each country like below:

```
def InvoicingDashboardView(request):
    # For reference - "c" is the context dictionary, and it's already initialized by this point

    for client in Client.objects.all():
        fte = frame.fte(c['start_date'], c['end_date'], time = 'external', client = client.id)

        if fte > 0:
            c['countrys'][client] = {
                'name': client.name,
                'fte': fte,
                'var_fte': fte - frame.fte(c['var_start_date'], c['var_end_date'], client = client.id),
                'daily_ftes': [frame.fte(day, day) for day in c['label_days']],
            }
    

    return render(request, 'dashboards/invoicing.html', context = c)
```

As you can see, for example, if i call `{{countrys.client.fte}}` i'll get the fte for that client.

Everything good till now, but i'll need the `daily_ftes` for a JS function, like below:

```
<div class="dash_countrys_ftes">
    {% for country, items in countrys.items %}
        <div class="dash_country_block">
        {% with name=items.name fte=items.fte variation=items.var_fte flag=country.flag.url %}
            {% include 'dashboards/charts/country_block.html' %}
        {% endwith %}
        </div>
        <script>
            countryFteVariation("{{items.daily_ftes|escapejs}}") // HERE
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The problem is that `daily_ftes` is a python list.

What can i do here in order to javascript read it as list instead of a string?

Comment: If you don't want a string, why do you write quotes?

Comment: convert it to json and then parse it with js.

Comment: @albar what do you mean? if i don't put the quotes then it'll just result in error. I assume you are referring to the quotes on `countryFteVariation("{{items.daily_ftes|escapejs}}") `

Comment: @go2nirvana can you put an answer and show me how to do it?

Comment: @Ricardo `items.daily_ftes` is a python list. `countryFteVariation` expects a js list as argument. Lists in python and js have the same representation. So if `{{`items.daily_ftes}}` returns the representation of the python list, `countryFteVariation({{items.daily_ftes}})` may work.

Comment: @albar Holy... you're right... I've only now realized that i was passing "nan" values inside the list. That's why it was giving me an error... I thought i had to do some magic in order to pass lists.. but guess not :D Thank you